# Winbugs: freeze after compile

Tags: winbugs

I wrote a code for MCMC estimation in WinBUGS14. It passes the check model, load data, but gets stuck right after compile. It shows that the program is "not responding", and has been frozen by more than 1 hour.

What does this mean? Does it mean the program has bug? Or does it mean the estimation is just too complicated?

Many thanks!

Jun

Comment: If it is a non-simple model It may well be running. In my experience, compilation speed it depends on how complex the model.